# Searching with or without spaces or special signs

Tags: magento-1.6, catalogsearch

In my store I've set the search type to "Combined" and I'm looking for the exact name that I use for my products.

The problem is that some articles use spaces, others use the "-" sign and the rest is written without any spaces or special signs.

How can I set it up so that for example:

My product name is KNG-HF2000

My search input could be KNGHF2000 or KNG-HF2000 or KNG HF2000

And the tricky part is, I only want that product to be the result for all search inputs.

Is there some way to configure that without having to change all my product names?

---

I was looking at [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3982/magento-quick-search-to-look-into-custom-attributes-with-conditions?rq=1).

But there has to be some sort of rewrite function to strip the name en search input of spaces and special signs, so u can compare them stripped results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in this case there are 2 ways to go about.

Either use the `Search Terms` in the backend under `Catalog` where you can add variations on the product name or look into using [Solr](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/solr-bridge-search.html).

Solr will make variations on the search term for you. Of course you could build something like that yourself in Magento overwriting the core search functionality but it will potentially be quite heavy on your server

Comment: Hi Sander, adding Search term would be alot of work to do this four thousand of products and Soir doesn't directly provide a solution towards the search or advanced search result pages. There has to be a simpeler way, but I don't know how the big e-shops solve this though :(

Comment: the danger with trying to solve this yourself with MySQL is high server load. You would have to search for partials of the search term which would be something like 'KNG%' OR 'KNGH%' OR 'KNGHF%' etc etc but the queries resulting from that would be very heavy. Big e-shops will probably also use something like Solr or Sphinx simple because plain MYSQL just isn't suited for heavy searching

Comment: Okay thanks for the info ;) You don't know of any free extensions that has the same basic function for the search?

Comment: No, we always implement Solr when a client asks for a more powerfull search. Perhaps you might be able to write a script that programmatically adds Search Terms for each product. Thats probably an easier way to go about it